# remove config default while uninstall plugin

Tags: default-value, shopware6

i have a plugin where i set config defaults at the installation - die "defaultValue" Option in the config.xml won't work out of the box:

```
    private function addDefaultConfiguration(): void
    {
        $this->setValue('hoverstyle', array('tile-border'));


    }
```

How can i remove this at the unistall method?

Can't find any hint at the developer pages

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this during the `uninstall` plugin lifecycle method.

The `SystemConfigService` has a `delete` method, with which you can delete single entries, or even the `deletePluginConfiguration` method, which should delete any entries of your plugin.

```
public function uninstall(UninstallContext $context): void
{
    parent::uninstall($context);

    if ($context->keepUserData()) {
        return;
    }

    $systemConfigService = $this->container->get(SystemConfigService::class);
    $systemConfigService->delete($this->getName() . '.hoverstyle');
}
```

Something like this should do the trick. Keep in mind, to only delete plugin data if `$context->keepUserData()` is false.